# Windows 10 store app runs on emulator but not on device

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-mobile

I used to run windows store app on solution config:Debug with platform x86 using Device mode but now when I am running it, it gives the following error

```
Unable to activate Windows Store app '{App}'. The {App name}.exe 
process started, but the activation request failed with error 'The app
didn't start'.
```

but this runs in Mobile emulator mode. I tried deleting build directories and cleaning solution but still I get the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the visual studio.
Try to run on local machine. 
and if no success Try with x64 platform.

Similar problem helped me with these ways. Hope this helps to you as well.